# Running Cucumber Scenarios in Parallel of Single Feature File

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have 2 feature file that include multiple scenarios, I want to run the scenarios of each feature file in parallel.

For example:

**example1.feature** *has 2 scenarios*

**example2.feature** *has 3 scenarios*

**How to run the five scenarios in parallel ?**

Thanks All :)

Comment: You can run feature files in parallel, not sure if you can run scenarios in feature files in parallel. Have a look at --- https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/ for testng --- https://automatictester.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/basic-cucumberjvm-selenium-webdriver-test-automation-framework/

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I've tried above examples, I don't see any example or data about running scenarios in parallel.
And i get error in the POM xml while using cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, execution tag is marked in red.

Comment: I have managed to crack this at work and get scenarios to run in parallel as well.. Just never found time to put it out in the open source.. Maybe I will try and do that.. but yeah as mentioned, you can currently only run features in parallel... not more than that..

Comment: Hi Krishnan, please share as soon as possible. It will be effective for all of us. Thanks :)